# How do I get find command in script to return result to variable?

Tags: bash

How can I get this find command to return the result into the variable? It works on the command line but in a script not so much.

```
BZIP_FILES="$(find /dev/runs/sample -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \"*L*_R1*.fastq.gz\" | sort | head -1)"
```

Directory /dev/runs/sample

```
17-ABCC7-A-02-00-R_GAATCTTCGC_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
17-ABCC7-A-02-00-R_GAATCTTCGC_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
17-ABCC7-A-02-00-R_GAATCTTCGC_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
17-ABCC7-A-02-00-R_GAATCTTCGC_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz
bak
fusion
SampleSheet.csv
```

Result should be 17-ABCC7-A-02-00-R_GAATCTTCGC_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz

Comment: So..  1) what result did you get? 2) why do you call `gzip` files `BZIP_FILES`?

Comment: The variable name is insignificant and the result is empty

Comment: remove the \ before the quotes: `BZIP_FILES="$(find /dev/runs/sample -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*L*_R1*.fastq.gz" | sort | head -1)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the escaped quotes to find with single quotes should work, i.e. `'*L*_R1*.fastq.gz\'`.

Answer (score 0):

between `$(` and `)` double quotes are syntactical, so `$()` can be nested easily.

For example

```
echo "$(echo "$(echo "ok")")"
```

Also '**' is not needed inside find -name option and must be quoted to avoid glob to be extended

```
BZIP_FILES="$(find /dev/runs/sample -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*L*_R1*.fastq.gz' | sort | head -1)"
BZIP_FILES="$(find /dev/runs/sample -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*L*_R1*.fastq.gz" | sort | head -1)"
```